# R lmer confint: theta values not the same as summary values

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme

I've been using lmer's confint procedure to compute bootstrapped confidence intervals for random effects.  I noticed that extracting the theta values using "getME" produces estimates that are slightly different from what the summary function provides.  Using the carrots dataset, here's the code:

```
m <- lmer(Preference ~ sens2+Homesize+(1+sens2|Consumer), data=carrots)

confint(m, method="boot", parallel="multicore", ncpus=4)
```

Now the summary function produces the following (some lines omitted):

```
REML criterion at convergence: 3748.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5322 -0.5571  0.0308  0.6297  2.8552 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Consumer (Intercept) 0.195168 0.44178      
          sens2       0.002779 0.05271  0.18
 Residual             1.070441 1.03462      
Number of obs: 1233, groups:  Consumer, 103

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   4.910021   0.070560 101.350000  69.586  < 2e-16 ***
sens2         0.070675   0.009545 102.010000   7.404 3.89e-11 ***
Homesize3    -0.249039   0.105374 100.960000  -2.3
```

Extracting beta (the fixed effects) produces identical estimates to those in the summary function.  But not so with theta:

```
getME(m,"theta")

Consumer.(Intercept) Consumer.sens2.(Intercept) 
         0.426995160                0.009354308 
            Consumer.sens2 
               0.050084579
```

I suspect that the discrepancy has something to do with the Cholesky parameterization of the random components as described [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lme4/docs/isREML).  Is there a way to extract the random estimates as they appear in the summary?  For practical purposes, I'd like to extract the random estimates in the same order as produced by the confint procedure, which getME does:

```
                                     2.5 %      97.5 %
sd_(Intercept)|Consumer         0.35051177  0.52851297
cor_sens2.(Intercept)|Consumer -0.32121878  0.65130350
sd_sens2|Consumer               0.02096827  0.07710528
sigma                           0.98997624  1.08073053
(Intercept)                     4.76700314  5.04259381
sens2                           0.05310008  0.08821807
Homesize3                      -0.45809294 -0.02700430
```

That way, one could easily create a middle column, one that contains the estimate, with the upper and lower bounds on either side.

On another note, confint uses standard deviation and correlations for the intervals.  Is there an option for it to use the unstandardized (variances/covariances) estimates?

Thanks in advance.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `as.data.frame(VarCorr(fitted_model))` (see `?VarCorr`) does what you want:

```
library("lme4")
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
summary(fm1)
## ...
## Random effects:
##  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
##  Subject  (Intercept) 612.09   24.740       
##           Days         35.07    5.922   0.07
##  Residual             654.94   25.592
cc <- confint(fm1,which=c("theta_",".sigma"))
cbind(as.data.frame(VarCorr(fm1), order="lower.tri"),cc)
##             grp        var1 var2       vcov       sdcor      2.5 %    97.5 %
## .sig01  Subject (Intercept) <NA> 612.089748 24.74044761 14.3815203 37.715996
## .sig02  Subject (Intercept) Days   9.604335  0.06555134 -0.4815007  0.684986
## .sig03  Subject        Days <NA>  35.071662  5.92213324  3.8011641  8.753383
## .sigma Residual        <NA> <NA> 654.941041 25.59181590 22.8982669 28.857997
```

Note that the confidence intervals (last two columns) are on the standard dev-correlation scale: if you want them on the var-cov scale I think you can get them with

```
confint(varianceProf(profile(fm1,which=c("theta_",".sigma"))))
```

(in principle: I'm running into trouble with this example, will have to look into it ...)

PS the `order="lower.tri"` option may be new in the development version ...

PPS if you want to get bootstrapped confidence intervals on another scale, look into the (also possibly only-in-development-version) `FUN` argument to `confint.merMod` ...

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  That solves the problem nicely.  Very impressed with lme4 v1.1-8.  Thanks for your hard work on that!

Comment: As a follow up, I'm intrigued by the FUN option because it would solve 2 problems.  First, the model I'm working with (3 levels, observations, nested within individuals, nested within groups) is parameterized to have a residual variance of 0, which lmer doesn't do. The quick fix is to add the residual variance to the ind-level variances, but that doesn't solve the problem of getting the right CIs. I wonder if a function could be written that adds the residual to the ind-level variances and then set the residual to 0.  Would the CIs be based on the new values for the individual-level variances?